# Magento installation error in my server

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

While installing magento community edition 1.7.0.2 in my server i saw an error message:

`"Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."`

Our PHP directives are:

```
memory_limit            90M
max_execution_time      30
```

And System Details are:

```
My System: Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i686
ServerAPI: Apache 2.0 Filter
```

In server logs my error is:

`Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: /index.php/install/wizard/config/?config`

Comment: open your index.php file and uncomment the display_errors line, and enable developer mode. this will show you more info about the error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ini_set("display_errors",1) is not commented
And also error_reporting(E_ALL);

Please paste all the error here (or use pastebin)
What's the file where the error occurs? And the line(s).

Comment: In server log my error is " Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer:  /index.php/install/wizard/config/?config